# State diagram, calculate the value after these functions

Tags: math, uml

I have this picture of a state diagram and have to calculate the value of x after a few events. The events are e1-e2-e2-e2-e2
The x would be 2 in the beginning.
First event is e1, so I think it would become 4 after that event.
Next is e2 and I was wondering because the exit is x=x-1, so would it go to state B, because it is less that 4, or C because it was 4, but became 3 in the exit?
And lets suppose it goes to B, and becomes 5, and we do e2 again. Would nothing happen because the only possibility is x>5 and it is equal to 5?

[image: state_diagram_calculation.png]

Comment: `e2[e>=4]` does not seem to make sense at all. Should be `x`? In any case: make a table with states entry/exit and go top down.

Comment: @qwerty_so yes clearly *e* must be read *x* because there is no *e* elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the guard between A and C is `x>=4` (since there is no `e` defined) I made a small transition table:

[image]

So the final state should be B and X is 11.

Comment: in A -> C you forgot A exit behavior x=x-1 (I had check the other answer and sim is right)

Comment: What about the exit of A? And shall "there is no e defined" mean? Every transition has a triggering event in this example.

Comment: @bruno I was sure I missed something like that. Thanks and fixed.

Comment: @sim Yes, Bruno noticed me already and I fixed it. I thought a tabular presentation is better for an overview. But that does not help when you're not carefull ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so you did by hand, me I defined the state machine in [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) with a C++ definition for the guards/behaviors, added the attribute *x* on the machine, used my _state machine generator_ to automatically create the classes supporting the machine with a C++ definitions, added an *artifact* for the *main* function with the few lines to instantiate the machine and do the required transitions, generated C++ code, compiled it with *VERBOSE_STATE_MACHINE* and run the program printing all. So I don't have any merit to know the result (out of having done BoUML ;-) )

Comment: @bruno yes, nice. State transition tables are another way to do it if you have paper and pencil. Got me a down vote, though. Well...

Comment: @qwerty_so, yes, no pity on S.O., probably because you forgot the exit behavior (wasn't me, but the UV is me, I previously UV the other answer of course)

Comment: @bruno Thanks :-) Well, somehow I'm used to that, but it still does not feel good...

Answer (score -1):

In UML state machines, the guards are evaluated, when beeing in the original state. I.e., when receiving e2 the first time, x is 4 and thus you take the transition to C, unser the assumption that e is x (otherwise it doesnt make sense) . After you decided going to C, and thus leave A, you aubstract 1 from x due to the exit ocndition. When beeing in C, you can change B by trigger of e2, which is unguarded (the guard x>5 belongs to the transition from B to C). Now x is 6, as you add 3 due to the entry condition. Then you receive the next e2 and transide to B, where you add 1, so x is now 7. When receiving the next e2, you check the guard on the transition to C, which demands that x is  greater 5, which holds. So lets go to C and execute the entry action once again. So x is now 10. Then you get one more e2, so the state changes to C and its entry action is executed, thus x is 11.

So after the execution of the given events, x is 11 and the statemachine is in state B.

Comment: _x is 4 and thus you take the transition to C_ Of course you can, because there's no constraint about x being anything.

Comment: Just add a note about the bug in the diagram and I take back the DV. Ain't to hard.